# iOS: After app launched, UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController==nil

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, uitraitcollection

I have some code called from my `viewWillAppear` that relies on the root view controller's traitCollection being valid. To my surprise, even by the time when viewWillAppear is called, `UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController` is still nil, long after it was set and `makeKeyWindow` was called.
Why would this be? What is actually going on? It seems like some reasonable assumptions have stopped being true.

Answer (score 2):

The revelation is that not only is keyWindow deprecated, but in fact non-functional and returns nil, after window has been assigned and viewWillAppear has been called.

Therefore, change to this:

```
    UIViewController *vc = UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows.firstObject.rootViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have not assigned `window` property on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

If you have no window property in App Delegate assign, it'll be retained

Do you have a similar code written?

```
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let mainVC = UIViewController()
        self.window?.rootViewController = mainVC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

By the way, `keyWindow` property [is now deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622924-keywindow)

Try this:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first({ $0.isKeyWindow })
```

Comment: But I did assign it. The problem was however that keyWindow is not only deprecated but Not Working. I switched to using UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows.firstObject.rootViewController and it works fine.